# Concatenating an integer based on an sql id for use in a html ID tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently building a website as part of my course. The website is an eCommerce site. I am storing the products in an SQL database, then echoing each row out into a table using a php script. I have managed to do this fine, however, I now wish to add a button on each product that will contain a href which adds that chosen product to a cart. The only problem is, to build the cart array I need the ID, and to set the ID in the loop you have to concatenate an integer, and I do not know how to do this in my script, here is what I currently have, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><br>".$row['Name']."</td><br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<td><img src=".$row['Image']."height='200' width = '200'"."</td><br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<td>Price: £".$row['Price']."</td><br>";
echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id=>Buy</a></button>";
echo "</tr>";
```

}

Thanks in advance, I hope I have given enough detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this.

```
$id = 123; // as an example. Use the appropriate variable for this.

echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id=$id>Buy</a></button>";

echo "<br>";

echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id=\"$id\">Buy</a></button>";
```

Which in HTML source reveals:

```
<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id=123>Buy</a></button><br><button type='button'>

<a href='test.php' id="123">Buy</a></button>
```

Depending on if you want them quoted or not, if that's what the question is about.

Or:

```
echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id='".$id."'>Buy</a></button>";
```

with HTML source revealing:

```
<button type='button'><a href='test.php' id='123'>Buy</a></button>
```

Then you can pull the data with a GET array.

I.e.:

```
$var = $_GET['id'];
```

then:

```
echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php?id=".$id."'>Buy</a></button>";
```

HTML source:

```
<button type='button'><a href='test.php?id=123'>Buy</a></button>
```

In your `while` loop, you could assign a variable to the id.

I.e.:

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

**I must note** that using single quotes could have adverse effects if your data contains single quotes, so it's best to use double quotes.

I.e.: (and escaping double quotes)

```
echo "<button type=\"button\"><a href=\"test.php?id=".$id."\">Buy</a></button>";
```

Producing this in HTML source:

```
<button type="button"><a href="test.php?id=123">Buy</a></button>
```

I had first hand experience with this last week actually, where HTML source revealed warnings about malformed HTML markup with data such as `Mark's Bar & Grill`.

---

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $id = $row['id']; // assuming you have a row for id.

    // all your other code

    echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php?id=".$id."'>Buy</a></button>";

}
```

For example:

```
$name = "Bob's Bar & Grill";

echo "<button type='button'><a href='test.php' name='".$name."'>Buy</a></button>";
```

Would produce a `No space between attributes` warning in HTML source.

From HTML source:

```
<button type='button'><a href='test.php' name='Bob's Bar & Grill'>Buy</a></button>
```

and could have adverse effects if used with CSS rules.

---

This would be related to your other row for the name `$row['Name']` etc.

- Be careful with that.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, this has sorted the code for me, as I am using a $_GET['id'] in another PHP script.

Comment: @dannstuff You're welcome, glad I could be of help. You did see my note about the use of single quotes? I had an issue myself last week and needed to resort to using double quotes. First time for everything I guess ;-) Live and learn as my 'ol pappy used to say. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry that it's an integer. Just use the value retuned from the db as you are doing for the strings. It will be converted from int to string. Also note that the concatenation you are doing to create strings is not really needed. Since php variables start with $, you can just write them inline like this:

```
echo "<button type='button'><a href=\"test.php\" id=\"$row['id']\">Buy</a></button>";
```